# SQL: Join multiple row value as columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with two different tables, first one called `'House'` and includes the following columns: `id, name, updated_at`. My second table is called `'House_meta'` and includes the following columns: `house_id, name, value`. In the meta table I have (for example) the following data:

```
house_ id      name        value
1              street      123 streetname
1              color       black
1              city        chicago
1              image       image-1.jpg
1              image       image-2.jpg
1              image       image-3.jpg
```

I need to join these tables so that each house entry is on one row only. My problem is the images, they all need to be on the same row and possibly be outputted like image1, image2, etc. My current SQL:

```
SELECT 
   house.id AS house_id, 
   house.name AS housename, 
   updated_at
   max(case when house_meta.name = 'street' then house.value end) as street,
   max(case when house_meta.name = 'color' then house.value end) as color,
   max(case when house_meta.name = 'city' then house.value end) as city,
   max(case when house_meta.name = 'image' then house.value end) as image
FROM house 
   join house_meta on house.id = house_meta.house_id
group by 
   house.id
```

This only (naturally) results in only one of the images being added. How can I do this so that all the images will end up on the one row?

How I want it returned:

```
house_id    updated_at   street          color   city      image1       image2        image3
1           2016-12-02   123 streetname  black   chicago   image-1.jpg  image-2.jpg   image-3.jpg
```

Comment: you want to look into `pivoting` concept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make a dynamic Pivot query. Please refer this link it will help you

[Like of Dynamic Pivot](http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/18/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server/)